# PrestoDB Mongo query taking too much time

Tags: mongodb, presto

I am running a query in PrestoDB through a MongoDB connector. The query fetches data from a single collection in MongoDB. The query is something like:

```
SELECT studentId, classId, sum(date_diff('DAY', entryTime, (CASE WHEN (exitTime <= TIMESTAMP '2018-04-15 23:59:59 UTC') THEN exitTime ELSE TIMESTAMP '2018-04-15 23:59:59 UTC' END))) as timeSpent 
FROM mongodb.school.student WHERE entryTime BETWEEN TIMESTAMP '2017-10-30 00:00:00 UTC' AND TIMESTAMP '2018-05-15 23:59:59 UTC' AND contains(classId, '1234') AND subject = 'Maths'
GROUP BY classId, studentId
ORDER BY timeSpent DESC;
```

I have about 8 million records in the collection and this query takes about 45 seconds to execute.

My PrestoDB is set up on a single Ubuntu instance acting as coordinator and worker with total RAM of 8GB. The `jvm.config` file looks like:

```
-server
-Xmx8G
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
-XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit
-XX:+AggressiveOpts
-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError
```

The `config.properties` file has the following config:

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=true
http-server.http.port=8080
query.max-memory=5GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://localhost:8080
```

The `-Xmx8G` was earlier `-Xmx4G` but I changed it to `-Xmx8G` to try but performance was almost the same. Am I:

- Using instance with too low RAM (8GB)?
- Should I try running PrestoDB as a cluster? What configuration is expected if there are to be about **60 million records** in that collection with this query?

Or is it something with my current configuration itself?

Comment: Have you been able to diagnose the bottleneck? Is this query cpu, memory, disk or network bound? I think you need to answer this first, then you will now where you need more resources.

Are you able to do the same (equivalent) query directly in mongo to see how fast your query when executed natively.

Comment: I executed the query in MongoDB in it returned results in 1.5 seconds only (maybe due to indexes I have defined in MongoDB which are not being considered by PrestoDB). How do I know the boundations of the query as you stated, can you provide any resources where I can study this?

Comment: Can you paste in the `mongodb.properties` connection file that you created? Also which version of Presto are you running?

Comment: @jpavs The `mongodb.properties` just contains the connector name, username, password, host and port for MongoDB. Also, I use `prestodb-0.198`.

Answer (score 0):

Please run EXPLAIN ANALYZE for your query in Presto and show us the output.
It should be clear which part of the query takes most of the time.

Comment: This is not the answer, please post such questions as comment to question. Cheers :)